# Is there an ending to Stardew Valley?

Tags: stardew-valley

Is there an end to Stardew Valley? Like an end cut-scene or end items? I've pretty much finished everything and was just wondering if there's a end.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Stardew Valley has no official end to it. You can keep playing for as long as you like.

The closest thing the game has to an ending is getting a perfect evaluation by your grandfather. At the beginning of year 3, your grandfather's ghost will appear and score you based on a multitude of categories. If you get a perfect score, he will award you a statue that gives you free Iridium every day. If you've acquired this statue, it's safe to say you've 'beaten' the game, outside of any achievements or personal challenges you wish to work towards.

Comment: Minor nitpick- this isn't a perfect score, just a high one. It's actually possible to get 4 candles without befriending a single visitor or interacting with the community centre.

Comment: @Studoku very interesting, wasn't aware of that, I had never personally looked into the details of how the evaluation is handled. Alas, it's still the best we have. That's why I included the mention of achievements though, to cover any gaps between what grandpa wants and what the devs could think of you doing.

Answer (score 4):

As of patch 1.5, there is an ending of sorts. You need to reach 100% Perfection in the Qi Walnut room, then unlock [the summit](https://stardewcommunitywiki.com/The_Summit). There's a cutscene that is basically an ending. The game keeps on going even after that (and you get a cool item for your troubles).